# How do I tell pandas to group the same months across multiple years?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataFrame comprised of datetimes in the format `21-JAN-2016` which I hit with `pd.to_datetime(df[0])`. I've trying to group my data such that the same month, across the span of several years, is plotted side-by-side. For example, the # occurrences in January for 2015, 2016, 2017, etc.. (So there'd be four bars side-by-side clumped together) And then the # occurrences in February for 2015, 2016, 2017, etc..

Right now I have the below code which I believe is working mostly, but I'm not sure because the x-axis is not labeling the months correctly. Right now it will throw a `AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'strftime'` but if I remove `index.strftime("%Y-%b")` it plots, just with a bad x-axis label and I'm not sure how I understand how to get it so that my label shows each of the 4 years, and beneath it, the month. This is my code as is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import calendar

file = 'dates.txt'

# Convert datetimes
df = pd.read_csv("dates.txt", header=None) # Format: 359  21-JAN-2016
df["dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])        # Format: 388  3-JUL-2015 2015-07-03

### Group data by year per month
by_year_per_month = by_year_per_month = df["dates"].groupby([(df.dates.dt.month),(df.dates.dt.year)]).count()
labels_by_year_per_month = by_year_per_month.index.strftime("%Y-%b")

### Label
by_year_per_month.plot(kind="bar", ax=ax)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels_by_year_per_month)

# Show plot
plt.show()
```

I thought I could format the month label using `df["dates"].groupby([(df.dates.dt.month.to_period('M')),(df.dates.dt.year)]).count()` but that gave me `AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'to_period'`.

BONUS:

Not sure if I can ask a second question here so please let me know if I should open a separate question but as a bonus I'd really like to know how to display each cluster of months on the graph such that they are side-by-side and there's a bit of a gap between it and the other groupings. i.e. Jan[15,16,17,18] is grouped up, then there's a space before Feb[15,16,17,18] rather than having even space between everything. Basically just to clean it up and make it easier to read.

EDIT 1:

Updated code to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import calendar

file = 'dates.txt'

# Convert datetimes
df = pd.read_csv("dates.txt", header=None) # Format: 359  21-JAN-2016
df["dates"] = pd.to_datetime(df[0])        # Format: 388   3-JUL-2015 2015-07-03

### Group data by month per year
result = df["dates"].groupby([df.dates.dt.month, df.dates.dt.year]).count().unstack()
#result.columns = result.columns.droplevel(0)
result.index.name = 'month'
result.plot(kind="bar")

# Show plot
plt.show()
```

Which gives me:

[image]

Comment: Please try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently grouping by month and year.  You just need to unstack the result into a table.

```
by_year_per_month.unstack()
```

You should then be able to plot your data.

```
dates = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2016-01-01', freq='d', periods=356 * 4)
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': dates, 'value': np.random.randn(356 * 4)})

# Summing sample data.  You want `count` in your example.
result = df.groupby((df.date.dt.month, df.date.dt.year)).sum().unstack()
result.columns = result.columns.droplevel(0)
result.index.name = 'month'
result.plot()
```

[image: result]

Comment: Edited original post with changes. looks super slick, so thank you for the help. I commented out the `result.columns` line because I was getting `AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'droplevel'`. I'm curious to know what it was meant to do since, without it, I am getting pretty excellent results.